# How can I set the color and alignment of attributed text in a UITextView in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring, textkit

The formatting of my textViews worked fine in iOS 6, but no longer in iOS 7. I understand with Text Kit much of the under the hood stuff has changed. It's become really quite confusing, and I'm hoping someone can help straighten it out a bit by helping me with something as simple as this.

My static UITextView originally was assigned a value for it's `textColor` and `textAlignment` properties. Then I made a `NSMutableAttributedString`, assigned it an attributes, then assigned it to the textView's `attributedText` property. The alignment and color no longer take effect in iOS 7.

How can I fix this? If these properties take no effect, than why do they exist anymore? Here's the creation of the textView:

```
UITextView *titleView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 90, 1024, 150)];
titleView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
titleView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

NSMutableAttributedString *title = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Welcome"];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:60];
[title addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, title.length)];
titleView.attributedText = title;

[self.view addSubview:titleView];
```

Answer (score 67):

Curious, the properties are taken into account for `UILabel` but not for `UITextView`

Why don't you just add attributes for color and alignment to the attributed string similar to the way you are doing with the font?

Something like:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *title = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Welcome"];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:60];
[title addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, title.length)];

//add color
[title addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, title.length)];

//add alignment
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[title addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, title.length)];

titleView.attributedText = title;
```

**Edit:** Assign the text first, then change the properties and this way it works.

```
UITextView *titleView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 90, 1024, 150)];

//create attributed string and change font
NSMutableAttributedString *title = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Welcome"];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:60];
[title addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, title.length)];

//assign text first, then customize properties
titleView.attributedText = title;
titleView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
titleView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: When I do this, the NSFontAttributeName attribute seems to no longer be take into effect. It centers fine, the color is fine, but the font size seems to be at system size. I tried applying the font attribute last after assigning all the other attributes first, and strangely the app crashes with `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICTFont textBlocks]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b1d1c0'`.

Comment: I suppose you are referring to the second alternative (assigning the text first, then modifying the properties), but in that example I didn't include the font customization, I will modify it to include the full sample.

Comment: Both code samples yield the same result for me. So assigning the UITextView's properties doesn't seem to be necessary. Was there a reason you put them in?

Comment: Yeah, both samples should produce the same result. I just added the second way (customizing UITextView's properties) because you were asking why they weren't taken into account in your example. In my opinion, I find my first example clearer to understand (working only with attributed string attributes) instead of mixing attributes and `UITextView` properties.

Comment: Oh ok. Are you not getting the font error I described in the first comment?

Comment: Thanks for the terrific example.